# should i use "Set" or "List"

Tags: java, list, collections, set

I'm learning Java.util.Collection and have encountered the following question and answer.

> Consider the four core interfaces, Set, List, Queue, and Map. For each
>   of the following four assignments, specify which of the four core
>   interfaces is best-suited, and explain how to use it to implement the
>   assignment.
>
> 1) Whimsical Toys Inc (WTI) needs to record the names of all its
>   employees. Every month, an employee will be chosen at random from
>   these records to receive a free toy.

The answer provided by the tutorial is

> Use a List. Choose a random employee by picking a number between 0 and
>   size()-1.

But I was just wondering shouldn't `Set` be used instead of `List`? Cause employees are unique individuals and we dont want the same employee to be entered multiple times. Is my thinking correct or am I missing something? Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: ArrayLists are commonly used, although a Set cannot contain duplicates. You can check for duplicates with an ArrayList, though.

Comment: @LoganKulinski thank you for the comment. Do you have any suggestions on whether I should use "Set" over "List" or vice versa?

Comment: @LoganKulinski oh ok, i c. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: You're welcome. List and Set are interfaces though, so you'll have to use a class that implements them. For example, the ArrayList class implements List.

Comment: I think these kind of assignments are good learning opportunity. Thanks for sharing. But I would strongly recommend that you post what have you worked on to solve your problem. In your specific case, the importance is given to names and random access. I assume you can have same names and so the uniqueness is not imp here. Most imp req is random access. So I guess it has enough info for you to think.

Comment: I'm curious what if "Tom" is picked for a free toy and there are multiple "Tom"s in that company...

Comment: @DROY will take it on board! Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But I was just wondering shouldn't `Set` be used instead of `List`? Cause employees are unique individuals and we don't want the same employee to be entered multiple times.

Although employees are unique individuals, their names may not be distinct. Using a `Set` would eliminate duplicates, incorrectly removing names of different employees with identical names.

Answer (score 2):

> employees are unique individuals and we dont want the same employee to be entered multiple times

This is a good thought, but you're making an assumption that isn't provided in the problem. The problem doesn't specify that names will ever be entered more than once, so attempting to de-duplicate the inputs would just be wasted effort.

More important than de-duplicating is that you need to *retrieve* a value from the collection, and `Set`s don't have an easy way to do that. You could iterate over them, but that's similarly wasteful. A [`RandomAccess`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) collection such as an `ArrayList` allows you to retrieve any arbitrary element in constant time.

The other answers also mention that you can't assume that employees have unique names. This is generally a good thing to remember about representing things like people, but the problem clearly assumes we'll ony have unique names since you wouldn't know *which* employee was being referred to if a duplicated name was selected from the list. This is why employees are generally associated with a unique ID in "real" applications.

Answer (score 2):

The List seems to be the better choice. Elements in the list can be accessed in constant time. If you are using ArrayList then you can use list.get(index) method to directly fetch the employee you want.

While if you chose to use Set then you will need to iterate the set till you find the randomly selected employee.

For e.g.

```
int size = empHashSet.size();
int employee = new Random().nextInt(size);
int i = 0;
for(Employee emp : empHashSet)
{
    if (i == employee)
        return emp;
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Hence, List clearly seems to be the correct choice.

Comment: actually, it is the other way around. List is O(n) aka linear, set is O(1) aka constant.

Answer (score 2):

**List seems to be a good choice:**

Create an object of every user, the name might be same but the other information can be different creating a separate object.

Put these objects under arrayList.

Override **hashCode and equals** to provide your logic of comparison.

[for instance, you can have variable ways to compare the object, maybe on age as one of the member variables which might be unique or **Employee Id which needs to be unique**, this will solve your duplication problem]

Now why does list help:

1. Indexing
2. You can avoid duplicates by checking the object by using list.contains(object o) (Along with your equals and hashCode implementation)

To select a random is very easy as it just needs Math.random or Random class object to refer to a random integer from the complete list.

Answer (score 0):

Names may contain duplicates. You can't have two Tom in a Set.

Comment: How would you know, from a list of names, *which* Tom your random result was referring to? The problem statement doesn't work with duplicate names, regardless of the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: As stated in the comments to the question it might be more interesting to understand the problem in more detail. In general, the answer to the question to use a concrete version of `List` or `Set` (like `ArrayList` or `HashSet`) is not that trivial.

Lemme elaborate a little bit why that is the case and thoughts you might have:

- Using an **ArrayList**: An `ArrayList` would be a good solution, if you know that you do not add the same `Employee` twice to your `List`. It could also be a good solution, if you know exactly when an `Employee` might be added a second time. In the latter case, you could check for an employee using something like:

  ```
  private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

  public void addEmployee(final Employee employee, final boolean check) {
      if (check) {
           Employee found = employees.stream().filter(e -> e.equals(employee)).findFirst().orElse(null);
           if (found == null) {
               this.employees.add(employee);
           }
       } else {
           this.employees.add(employee);
       }
  }
  ```
- Using a **HashSet**: Is faster if the chance of adding duplicates is the general case. It is slower when accessing the randomly picked `Employee` (see Varun Risbud posts).

You should not forget, that in both cases the `Employee` has to have an `equals` function (see e.g. [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)). In addition, when using a `HashSet` the implementation of the `Employee` needs to override 'hashCode' as well.